# Function to count the the position of the first occurrence of item ‘y’ in sequence ‘z’

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGi5S.png)We need to make a function that takes a list `z` and returns the index at which `y` first occurs. For example, if it's the second item in the list it will return `1`, etc. We only use `for` loops, `if else` statements and boolean values.

My function is working for all the number values I have been given, however when I put in a string as a list it only returns me one.

```
def positionfirst(z,y):
    val=0
    for item in y:
        if z!=item:
            val+=1
            if val==len(y):
                return None
        else:
            return val
```

Comment: Give an example of input and output that you don't understand.

Comment: For example when I input these values: 'print(positionfirst(2,[2,3,5,7]))'I get 0 returned which is the correct value. However If I input 'print(positionfirst("d","abcdefg"))' It only returns me either none or 0

Comment: Worked for me (got 3). You're not showing something.

Comment: @kabanus I just took a screencap and uploaded it there. It is still not working for me!

Comment: I don't want to start a discussion here, but the image you posted gives my 3 when I run it. If you're using something like eclipse to run, make sure the proper configuration is running and that you saved the file.

Comment: Im using Idle and its just not running correctly for the string that Is whats frustrating me! As I believe my logic behind the code should be working!

Comment: restart the kernel if using idle, and then run again

Comment: Write a new question about running in idle, and give this example which I'm not familiar enough with. there is no problem in your code. You can say it worked for someone else in eclipse.

Comment: [str.find()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture shows your error:

```
print((positionfirst('d', ['abcdefg'])))
```

Will return 0, as `'d' != 'abcdefg'`, which is the only element in `['abcdefg']`. You probably want

```
print((positionfirst('d', 'abcdefg'))).
```

This way the for loop iterates over the chars in the string. You can add a

```
print(item)
```

in your loop, to see what is happening. The first version will give

```
'abcdefg'
```

the second

```
'a'
'b'
'c'
'd'
'e'
'f'
'g'.
```

Those are the items you will compare against. Finally a bit shorter version of your function:

```
def positionfirst(z, y):
    val = 0
    for item in y:
        if z == item:
            return val
        val += 1
    return None
```

Comment: Ah yes you are right! I just ran It there and It worked! Thank you guys alot This is a great community here!